# Migrated files to Sharepoint is more than what is in the fileshare?

Tags: migration, spo

I have migrated about 19.5 GB files and folders to Share Point online from File Share with Microsoft Migration Tool .

In sharepoint i seem to have more files.

For example when go into same  folder in sharepoint and fileshare Their content are ;

**SharePoint**

~$H Limited
~$H Limited
APH Limited
APC Limited                                         .
KLM Limited

**FileShare**

APH Limited
APC Limited
KLM Limited
..........

What I mean is that Sharepoint contains what is in FileShare also it has extra files in it starts with **~$...**

I thought they may be the hidden files in fileshare but seems like there is actually no hidden files on that folder that i inspect.

Why does it happen? How can i avoid it guys?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

files starting with ~$H Limited are temporary files where users editing documents.

[Documentation here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files)

In migration tool you can set some filters in **Advanced Settings**:
[image]

**try disable: Migrate Hidden files:**
[image]

.

**and if its not working try disable: Migrate files and folders with invalid characters:**
[image]